# autocomplete in MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#

having a problem about making the AutoComplete work in my project. I'm using MVC4. I've followed everything properly using the Json part. I'm not sure if the problem is on jQuery or on my Controller.
Following is the code

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
        return View(db.Employees);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string Search_Data)
    {
        EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
        List<Employee> employees;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_Data))
        {
            employees = db.Employees.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            employees = db.Employees
                .Where(s => s.EmpName.StartsWith(Search_Data)).ToList();
        }
        return View(employees);
    }
    public JsonResult GetEmployees(string term)
    {
        EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
        List<string> employees = db.Employees.Where(s => s.EmpName.StartsWith(term))
            .Select(x => x.EmpName).ToList();
        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The following script used in my index.cshtml

```
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetEmployees","Employee")',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the GetEmployees Method Doesnt get Hit , i am able to search data by entering a string but autocomplete is not working.

Comment: are you getting some error in console?

Comment: No i am not getting any error

Comment: is your action getting called?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing an important script file:

[Unobtrusive Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/)

I've fallen for this issue many times. The jQuery autocomplete uses the jQuery ajax function and this only works with MVC if you include the Unobtrusive Ajax script.

Comment: I INCLUDE Unobtrusive Ajax script but of no use, autosearch still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error and was put scripts in another area, so

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
<script src="~/Scripts/MyApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```